# What is the difference between Disappointed and Disillusioned?

Tags: differences, emotions

I am learning emotional vocabulary.

I stuck a bit with two emotion terms, that in Russian refers to the same world.

Can you help me to understand the difference between **[Disappointed](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/disappointed)** and **[Disillusioned](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/disillusioned)**?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This question would be improved by adding evidence of research in English. Certainly I can see how Oxford's definitions of [disappointed](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/disappointed) and [disillusioned](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/disillusioned) don't exactly help.

Comment: Consider that "disillusion" is the prefix "dis" with the word "illusion".  You can derive the meaning from that.  But "disappointed" has shifted meanings over the centuries -- it originally meant being removed from an appointed position, but figurative uses gradually changed it's meaning to make that original one obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulling from your definitions:

You are disappointed in a situation, or a person, if you *hoped* **or** *expected* a certain outcome that failed to come to pass.

You are disillusioned, on the other hand, if you *believed* something that turned out not to be true.

Disillusionment is a subset of disappointment, and conveys a deeper feeling.